# C# How can I print all elements from List<Dictionary<string,string>> on the console?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I’m a rookie in programming and I have a problem understanding how to print elements from a List.
In the task I’ve been given, I receive:

```
List<Dictionary<string,string>>() list = new 
List<Dictionary<string,string>>(); 
list.Add(processString(string, string));
list.Add(processString(string, string));
```

The processStrig is a `Dictionary<string,string>` and the keys are the same for both records.

I tried to create a new `Dictionary` and then populate it with `foreach`:

```
    Dictionary<string,string>() dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (Dictionary<string,string>r in list)
    {
        foreach (string inner in r.Keys)
        {
            if (!dict.ContainsKey(inner))
            {
                dict.Add(inner, r[inner]);
            }
        }
    }
```

and then print the new dict with another `foreach`, but it shows me only the first input because the keys are the same. So basically my question is how to print the both inputs? The output should look like this:

The output should look like this:

```
[0]
"count":"some string"
"order":"some string"
[1]
"count":"some other string"
"order":"some other string"
```

Comment: How do you want to format your `list`?  If you are only printing for debugging purposes and don't care much about the format you could simply serialize to JSON and print that, e.g. via `var text = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(list, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });` ... Oh I see, the required format was shown in your original question without proper formatting.  But why are you trying to add the inner dictionaries to some big outer dictionary?  Why not just loop through the list, print a counter, then print each inner dictionary, using nested `foreach` loops?

Comment: At first learn what is a dictionary and  how to use , here for example. https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-dictionary . Only after this ask questions if you still need

Comment: Note that `Dictionary<TKEY,TVALUE>` implements enumeration on `KeyValuePair`: use `foreach (var entry in r) Console.WriteLine($"\"{entry.Key}\": \"{entry.Value}\"");`

Comment: *and the keys are the same for both records.* - but the values differ? You call `processString` (note: C# methods should have PascalCase names) twice, and it produces different results each time?

Comment: thank you guys for the answers. @Serge, thank you for the given resources! I needed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a *loop* solution, you can try something like this:

```
 List<Dictionary<string, string>> list = ...

 for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i) { 
   Console.WriteLine($"[{i}]");

   if (list[i] == null)
     Console.WriteLine("[null]");
   else 
     foreach (var pair in list[i])
       Console.WriteLine($"\"{pair.Key}\" : \"{pair.Value}\"");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a method that makes you a dictionary:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> MakeMeADictionary(string value1, string value2){
  var d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  d["key1"] = value1;
  d["key2"] = value2;
  return d;
}
```

Let's call it twice, adding the results to a List:

```
var listOfDicts = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

listOfDicts.Add(MakeMeADictionary("first val", "second val"));
listOfDicts.Add(MakeMeADictionary("third val", "fourth val"));
```

Let's enumerate the list, and then each dictionary inside it:

```
foreach(var dict in listOfDicts){

  Console.WriteLine("Enumerating a dictionary");

  foreach(var keyValuePair in dict)
    Console.WriteLine($"Key is: {keyValuePair.Key}, Value is: {keyValuePair.Value}");

}
```

Result:

```
Enumerating a dictionary
Key is: key1, Value is: first val
Key is: key2, Value is: second val
Enumerating a dictionary
Key is: key1, Value is: third val
Key is: key2, Value is: fourth val
```

Strive for variable names that make your code make sense; plurals or names of colelction types for collections, foreach vars that singularly make sense for the plural being enumerated etc.. If this were a less contrived example, and e.g. it were a `List<Person>` I'd call it `people`, perhaps, and have `foreach(var person in people)`.. I couldn't understand your choice of `r` in `foreach(var r in list)`